# How to add space inside HTML Label between text and colon for different length text for perfect alignment?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want to design a label as follows

```
Employee Name  :
Employee ID    :
Date of Birth  :
Age            :
```

I use tab button to align all the colons evenly. But when I use the code like the below in MVC html view design, it never comes so perfectly aligned as above.
I  write code as

```
<p class="form_text1">
       Employee Name      : </p>
  <p class="form_text1">
       Employee ID        : </p>
```

The output comes as

```
Employee Name:
Employee ID:
Date of Birth:
Age:
```

This one not nice. I want the design like neat one that I mentioned on first.

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from using a table for this instead?

Comment: Is the use of bootstrap allowed?

Comment: I cannot use table.. but I can use bootstrap. . any related code in bootstrap ?

Comment: set it as `<div class="row"><div class="col-md-2">employee name</div><div class="col-md-10">:</div></div>` replace md with xs if you don't want your list to collapse down upon resizing.

Comment: You can define your own css class and apply it on your label for `min-width`

Comment: chun  yin when I tried your one, output comes as "Employee" in first line and the "Name" comes in 2nd line

Comment: @Hal try using the code that I provided in the answer below. Just click on the **Run code snippet** button below to my answer and you can see the output...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that easily by defining your own style. Try to add your label text in a span and apply css on it.

```css
p.form_text1>span {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<p class="form_text1"><span>Employee Name</span>:</p>
<p class="form_text1"><span>Employee ID</span>:</p>
<p class="form_text1"><span>Date of Birth</span>:</p>
<p class="form_text1"><span>Age</span>:</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. its working .. But I got one doubt in dis .. My Label color is displayed as black before I use span tag.. after using this , the color of the text in labels looks dull.. how to rectify it?

Comment: You can just add style `color: #000000;` to the style defined above. And it will work for you.

Comment: @Hal Please post it as a new question because I can't type/paste the whole answer in a comment. It will be easier to read and answer to your problem. Thanks :)

Comment: I asked my question in following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110194/how-to-design-label-with-data-in-mvc-neatly?noredirect=1#comment75240183_44110194

Answer (score 0):

As Chun Yin already mentioned, a table can do this for you:

```
<table border="0">
  <tr><td>Employee Name</td><td>:</td><td><!-- input field--></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Employee ID</td><td>:</td><td><!-- input field--></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Date of Birth</td><td>:</td><td><!-- input field--></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Age</td><td>:</td><td><!-- input field--></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there any other option instead of using table..?

Comment: There's dozens of ways to do this, bootstrap, css, javascript etc etc.  What're you looking for?

Comment: In fact, you can even do this in raw HTML using  &nbsp; as a replacement for spacebar. (Not recommended, but I think this is what you're looking for.)

Comment: I tried this following method. it works too .<p class="form_text1" >
                                                Full Name &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;: </p>  But this one got long code and the nbsp varies for different field length.

Comment: @Hal try using the code that I provided in the answer. Hopefully it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The other way around for this is to use [pre](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) html tag.

```html
<p class="form_text1">
<pre>Employee Name : </pre></p>
<p class="form_text1">
   <pre>Employee ID : </pre></p>
<p class="form_text1">
<pre>Date of Birth : </pre></p>
<p class="form_text1">
   <pre>Age   : </pre></p>
```