# How to design label with data in MVC neatly?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I had designed a web page using bootstrap panel in mvc with 3 column that fixed with the PC screen. Design as below:

```
Employee Name  :             Address  :                Email        : 

Employee Age   :             Country  :                Contact No   :
```

This one fixed inside the PC Screen. But the problem is if the name/address/email is longer , then the data displays like below.

```
Employee Name  :  Amar       Address  : XXXXXXXX       Email        : abcde@
Arvind Antony                XXXX                      gmail.com                
Employee Age   :  26         Country  : yyyyy          Contact No   :
```

But I want to display as follows to provide neatly.

```
Employee Name  :Amar       Address  : XXXXXXXX       Email        :abcde@
                Arvind                XXXX                         gmail.com                
Employee Age   : 26        Country  : yyyyy          Contact No   :
```

How to make display like this ? 
The code we used in View is

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" @*data-parent="#accordion"*@ href="#collapse1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>Personal Particulars</a> </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                        <p class="mar_top_20"><img id="EmpImage" src="~/Content2/dist/img/dummy_image.jpg"  alt="" class="img-responsive"></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                        <p class="form_text1">
                                            <span>Full Name</span> :
                                            <strong id="EmployeeName">-</strong> </p></div></div></div>
```

I gave only one label set code for sample. 
The output we retrieve using id using jquery. Inside the jquery function I use the following line to get data from my table

```
 $('#EmployeeName').text(response.EmpName);
```

Comment: Put the employee name in a different column than the text "Employee name".

Comment: Absolutely, you need to use column structure to achieve this as Mr Lister says - also post your code if you need help with that structure.

Comment: I update my question with code. Is this code enough?

Comment: Im not using table in the above design and I am new to MVC & bootstrap. kindly help

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to experiment with a 6-column layout.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row r1">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">Label1</div><div class="col-sm-2">Value1 Value1 Value1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">Label2</div><div class="col-sm-2">Value2 Value2 Value2</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">Label3</div><div class="col-sm-2">Value3 Value3 Value3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

You are basically sharing a column for both the label and its value which is why you don't get the expected layout. Instead, you need to separate these into their own columns.

So you end up with pairs of columns:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">Employee Name</div>
<div class="col-sm-2"><strong id="EmployeeName"></strong></div>
```

Comment: sorry I got confuse with this code. from which line I need to change my code with your code.?

Comment: You are basically sharing a column for both the label and its value. You need to separate these into their own columns.

Comment: apologize for late reply.. So far I tried your code, but the output not come as my expected one. but I thought your code is correct , that I need to re assign some previous code. so that I will update u tmrw, whether this one worked or not..